# How do I use jQuery to remove last <li> from a <ul>?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an unordered list as such:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

What jQuery selector could I use to select the last li tag for removal? Here is what I have so far:

$('#myList').remove();

Answer (score 9):

use `:last-child` to select last li element and remove it.

```
$('#myList li:last-child').remove();
```

Comment: does last child work in ie7?

Answer (score 3):

I would say `$('li', ul).last().remove()`. This first selects all `li` elements inside of `ul` (which is expected to be a reference to an actual `ul` element, or to a jQuery object that's selected the `ul` element that you want to look inside). Then calling `.last()` selects just the last element from the previous selection, and then obviously `.remove()` removes it.

Comment: Might be helpful to add a explanation about what this is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li:last-child')
```

That will select the last li that is a child of the unordered list, and can be removed from there

Comment: You're missing quotes around your selector.

Comment: will last-child selector work in IE7? this is why i was asking here, sorry.

Comment: It will do yes, works right back to IE6

Comment: (Addition) - This does require jQuery version 1.x, as 2.x has dropped compatibility with IE8 and below